# Replace wp-content in image urls wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I've changed my wp-content folder to a folder called stuff and am trying to change my image urls in existing posts with a function rather than a SQL query...

I've placed this in my function.php hoping it would work, but the images are still using the 'wp-content' folder?

```
define('WP_UPLOADSURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
add_filter( 'pre_option_upload_url_path', function( $upload_dir_uri ){
    return str_replace( WP_UPLOADSURL . '/wp-content/', WP_UPLOADSURL . '/stuff/', $upload_dir_uri );
});
```

Comment: "I've changed my wp-content folder to a folder called stuff" why you did that?

Comment: because I don't want a wp-content folder!

Comment: ? That answer make as much sense as "I don't want wheels on my car! please fix!".

Comment: @vard? That is a perfectly acceptable answer.I don't want anyone to know I'm using WordPress and for security I would prefer not to be using the default wp-content folder.

Comment: @vard why should I justify WHY I want to change the folder name? I just want to know HOW to change the existing image urls?

Comment: For security reason? If you replace the name of wp-content to whatever, anyone will know that "whatever" value, so it doesn't change anything. And "I don't want anyone to know I'm using WordPress" changing the wp-content name will not prevent us to know that you're using it.

Comment: @vard, WHY has nothing to do with my question!

Comment: Flagged. Funny thing is that it's not the first time you're trying to mess with me. You should consider accept that people ask question about what you're asking and stop insult people and learn what respect means.

Comment: @vard. It shouldn't matter why i'm doing it... As i said above, I just want to know HOW?

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_upload_dir#Folder_Name

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to add the filter to `the_content` not the `pre_option_upload_url_path`.

```
define('WP_UPLOADSURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/');
add_filter( 'the_content', function( $upload_dir_uri ){
    return str_replace( WP_UPLOADSURL . '/wp-content/', WP_UPLOADSURL . '/stuff/', $upload_dir_uri ); /* Again Change stuff */
});
```